# What do models do on the catwalk?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, word-usage

What is the appropriate verb that I should use to fill in the blank below?

> People march on parades, but models **__** on the catwalk.

Comment: They [do their little turns](http://youtu.be/39YUXIKrOFk?t=57s).

Comment: @ApisUtilis, good to see I’m not the only one with good taste in music here! ;-)

Comment: @ApisUtilis: instantly recognizable even without the link. It deserves to become idiom :-)

Comment: I think the first part is somewhat hinting that the expected solution is "People march on parades, but models parade on the catwalk."

Comment: Also, I believe that people march *in* parades.  Compare that to being "on parade", which is somewhat different (though I can't pinpoint how).

Comment: @Richard If I heard that people were marching on a parade, I'd assume they were protesting against it, or possibly attempting to suppress it by means of overwhelming force.

Comment: @user867 Aah, perfect!  Thanks for the example and support.  "Marching on a paradae" definitely sounds like protest.

Answer (score 21):

If the OP requires a verb or an idiomatic expression then consider the following:

The models [*strut (their stuff*)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/strut+their+stuff) on the catwalk:

> from the literal meaning of *strut* (to walk proudly in a way that attracts attention)

Alternatively, models *[(strike a) pose](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/04/29/article-2615775-1D6FEC1A00000578-249_634x417.jpg)* on the catwalk.

Comment: While it is of course true that models strike poses on catwalks, I wouldn’t use that expression as a parallel to marching in parades. Striking a pose is what they do whenever they _stop_ walking and arrange their arms and legs in various awkward and unnatural positions for the benefit of the flashing cameras; so you could almost say it’s what they do when they’re not doing the verb Loureiro is looking for.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet and would you consider the expression "walk on the catwalk" a typical one? It sounds awkward to my ears. I'm not suggesting it is wrong, but I dislike how it rolls off my tongue. *Strike a pose* evokes fashion, moda, Vogue, etc.

Comment: “The model walked down the catwalk” sounds natural enough to me, if perhaps somewhat ‘flat’. I’d probably be more likely to say, “The model paraded/sashayed/strode down the catwalk”, just to evoke fashion and all that—but I wouldn’t say, “The model struck a pose down the catwalk”. Rather, “The model strode down the catwalk, striking poses now and again” or something like that. Striking a pose certainly evokes all the right images, but it’s not parallel to _walking_ or _marching_.

Comment: I'd say *glided*, or even *stumbled* considering the lengths of some of their heels. You do express yourself well, @JanusBahsJacquet you have a natural flair with words. You must be in the world of advertising, or editing.

Answer (score 16):

The models *walk* on the catwalk. Unsurprisingly.

Indeed, from that, one instance of a model presenting an outfit is called *a walk* as well.

Comment: There’s something appealing to the notion of models **pussyfooting** down the **catwalk**, even though that’s nearly the opposite of what they actually do.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  Also, I've always heard that they "walk the catwalk" not "walk *on* the catwalk".  +1

Comment: Never did a possible word enter into my mind other than this one. Though sashay is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 11):

You could use the word *sashay*.

> walk in an ostentatious yet casual manner, typically with exaggerated movements of the hips and shoulders. [(Oxford University Press, online)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sashay)
>
> Examples
> "The model sashayed down the runway." [(Merriam-Webster, online)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sashay)

I think it can serve in a figurative sense, so they don't have to be walking in any particular way. Analogously, people marching in a parade aren't always marching in the more conventional literal sense (as in military or a marching band), but may just be walking.

Comment: If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Comment: @tchrist I've added citations that I think are sufficient. Let me know if I'm wrong here. =)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that’s exactly what I was hoping for. +1 and a badge for you.

Answer (score 4):

> Models [**parade**](http://www.latimes.com/news/nationworld/world/la-0920-world02_jombnikn,0,523476.photo#axzz30lsDay45) on or [**stomp**](http://www.examiner.com/article/kevin-and-dani-jonas-backstage-with-rep-chage-at-new-york-fashion-week) the catwalk.

Alternately, models [**catwalk**](http://www.stylestrandfashion.com/charleston-fashion-week-2013-emerging-designers-sabrina-spant/) on the runway.

Answer (score 3):

You can also say *to model* on a catwalk.

Answer (score 2):

They [do their little turn, then shake their little toosh](http://www.lyricsondemand.com/onehitwonders/imtoosexylyrics.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think strut is actually a really good word.  But so are **pose** and **sell**.  They sell themselves and the outfits.  They are in a continuous pose knowing that the cameras are going non-stop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be elegant about it, I'd suggest "promenade".

Comment: A person "promenading" is usually enjoying themselves (while well-dressed). From the grim look on the face of a typical model, I wouldn't say they were enjoying it. Maybe their stiletto heels are killing them?

Comment: @PhilPerry: The definition I'm used to is closer to "take a leisurely walk, ride, or drive in public, especially to meet or be seen by others." That may not suit all models in all clothing, but I think it's appropriate to at least some, and I don't see enjoyment as a necessary part of the definition. (Indeed, your "usually" recognizes that it's not a very strong binding.)

Comment: I'm also biased, I admit, by having heard "prominade them around the ring" used to describe displaying animals for show or for sale... which is much the same kind of scenario from the audience's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I instantly thought of Madonna's "[Vogue](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuJQSAiODqI%E2%80%8E)"

From [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Avogue):

[image: Google definition]

Comment: Voguing is Madonna's about as much as twerking is Miley Cyrus'.

Comment: Madonna's Vogue, the song, is what I was referring to.

Comment: Where are those definitions from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.